# Skip validation for some members in associated models during create/update

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1, model-associations

I have the following 4 models

```
Hotel (name)
  has_one :address
  has_one :contact
  has_one :bank_account
  validates_presence_of :name
  def build_dependencies
    build_contact
    build_address
    build_bank_account
  end

Address (phone, street_address, hotel_id)
  belongs_to :hotel
  validates_presence_of :phone, :street_address

Contact (name, email, hotel_id)
  belongs_to :hotel
  validates_presence_of :name, :email

BankAccount (name, number, hotel_id)
  belongs_to :hotel
  validates_presence_of :name, :number
```

In a form used to create a Hotel, I take input for both name and email for the Contact model but only phone for the Address model.

```
HotelController#new
  @hotel = Hotel.new
  @hotel.build_dependencies #this creates empty Contact and Address to generate the form fields
  #render the form to create the hotel

HotelController#create
  #receive form data
  @hotel = Hotel.new
  @hotel.build_dependencies
  @hotel.save :validate => false
  @hotel.attributes = params[:hotel]
  @hotel.save :validate => false
```

This is the only way I was able to create a Hotel with contact information, phone from address and empty bank account. I had to call

```
@hotel.save :validate => false
```

the first time to save the Hotel instance with blank instances of BankAccount, Address, Contact. Then I had to update_attributes on contact and address and then

```
@hotel.save :validate => false
```

to ensure that the original form data got saved completely as expected.

This, beyond doubt, is a very bad piece of code. Can anyone tell me how to clean this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Address
  validates_presence_of :phone, :on => :create, :if => proc { |u| u.creating_hotel? }
  validates_presence_of :street, :phone, :on => :update

Contact
  validates_presence_of :name, :email :on => :update

def creating_hotel?
  addressable_type == 'Hotel'
end
```

The user sees the `:street, :name, :email` fields only after the hotel is created and `:phone` during the creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter, namely the `after_create` to call the associated model to create associated records after saving of the `@hotel` variable.

I happen to be facing the same problem and here's my solution. Sorry this probably is not helpful after such a long while but it'll be good for future users.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :bank_account

# Filter -- After Creation
after_create :create_default_bank_account

def create_default_bank_account
  self.build_bank_account
  self.bank_account.save(:validate=>false) 
  # :validate=>false must be called on the bank_account's save. I made the mistake of trying to save the user. =(
end
```

This way, you can take the empty row creation out of the `create` action, which IMHO, should belong to the Model. You can then use the `edit` action to let users "create" the bank account entry. Using this, you only need a standard create action (e.g. generated by `rails g scaffold_controller`).

**Update**: I re-read your question after answering and found myself to be more confused. I assume you want to render a form where the user is not expected to enter the bank account immediately but edit it later on another page.